Restart the computer Twice using combination of Batch or VBS, and PowerShell scripts on Computer
I aim to create a PowerShell Script that restarts the computer twice; however, I have some doubts about this way that I am aiming to do this task. I write the following script with a Start-Sleep in between to Restart-Computer -Force:
The script looks a bit like this:
Restart-Computer -Force

Start-Sleep -Seconds 300

Restart-Computer -Force

Issue is the computer reboots once and it does not reboot again. I have a gut feeling that this wrong  however, I know there is another way using scheduled tasks. However, when I think about the action I think it is shutdown /r so I tried this:
PowerShellScript1.ps1
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$file1='',

    [string]$file2='',

    [string]$file3=''
)
$mypath = $PSCommandPath
$cwd = $PSScriptRoot
if ( (-not [String]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($file2)) -and [String]::IsNullorWhiteSpace($file3))
{
    $taskname = "LLM"
    $taskExists = Get-ScheduledTask | Where-Object {$_.TaskName -like $taskName }

    if($taskExists) {
    Unregister-ScheduledTask -Taskname "LLM" -Confirm:$false
    } 
    
    $taskTrigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -AtLogOn 
    $taskname = "LLM"
    $taskAction = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "powershell.exe" -Argument "-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File $mypath -file1 $file2"
    # Describe the scheduled task.
    $description = "Automation Testing"
    $Principal = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -UserID "$env:USERDomain\$env:USERNAME" -LogonType ServiceAccount -RunLevel Highest
    # Register the scheduled task
    try{Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName $taskName -Action $taskAction -Principal $Principal -Trigger $taskTrigger -Description $description
    shutdown -r}
    catch{
    Write-Host $_
    }
}
elseif((-not [String]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($file2)) -and -not [String]::IsNullorWhiteSpace($file3)){
    $taskTrigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -AtLogOn 
    $taskname = "LLM"
    $taskAction = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "powershell.exe" -Argument "-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File $mypath -file1 $file2 -file2 $file3"
    # Describe the scheduled task.
    $description = "Automation Testing"
    $Principal = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -UserID "$env:USERDomain\$env:USERNAME" -LogonType ServiceAccount -RunLevel Highest
    # Register the scheduled task
    try{Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName $taskName -Action $taskAction -Principal $Principal -Trigger $taskTrigger -Description $description
    shutdown -r}
    catch{
    Write-Host $_
    }
}
if ( [String]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($file2))
{
    Unregister-ScheduledTask -Taskname "LLM" -Confirm:$false
    shutdown -r
}

PowerShellScript2.ps1
shutdown /r

PowerShellScript3.ps1
shutdown /r
Unregister-ScheduledTask 'LLM' -Confirm:$false

main2.ps1
Start-Process -WindowStyle hidden -Wait powershell -ArgumentList "$PSScriptRoot\PowerShellScript1.ps1", "$PSScriptRoot\.ps1", "$PSScriptRoot\PowerShellScript3.ps1"

Now I have two ways of calling main2.ps1 I can either use VBS, or Batch. I wrote a batch file that on one-click it runs as admin, and a VBS script on one-click that runs as admin.
I am experiencing difficulty getting the script to cycle through two restarts. I was thinking of writing an exe in C++ or C# to use instead of PowerShell Script files but was unsure whether that would work.

Would sending the restart command from a 2nd computer be an option for your scenario? ie. shutdown -r -m \machinename This way you wouldn't lose the script execution and you could monitor the reboot process with a combination of ping and another "is booted machine" mechanism. That's the way I would implement that.

@P-L I only have access to this one computer.

In that case yes you could do this through a scheduled task using the /sc onlogon flag or via the windows startup folder or registry Run folder, depending if there's a user logon in the process or not.


The simplest approach is to use the user-specific RunOnce registry key to specify a one-time action for the next time the current user logs on again:
Read-Host 'Press Enter to initiate the 1st restart.'

Set-ItemProperty HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce (New-Guid) @'
powershell.exe -noprofile -c "Read-Host \"Press Enter to restart again.\"; Restart-Computer -Force"
'@

Restart-Computer -Force

Note:

The above includes an interactive prompt before each reboot; simply remove the Read-Host statements for fully automated operation.

Set-ItemProperty is used to:

create a value in the HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce   registry key (expressed in terms of the HKCU: PowerShell drive)
... with a random name designed not to collide with any preexisting values ((New-Guid))
... and data that specifies a PowerShell CLI (powershell.exe) command that effects a second restart.


By design - given that any commands specified there should only execute once - Windows automatically deletes such a registry value on execution (during the next logon, in this case).


